# Internet connection partly not working: Some websites do not load

Tags: router, internet, internet-connection, modem, cable-modem

I am on an internet over cable connection. Cable modem is a combined device including router and wlan hotspot.

Since yesterday I experience strange network behaviour - nothing changed on any settings or devices at all:

- internet connection is generally available
- however, some domains / websites are not available. When called in any browser on any device, browsers return timouts

  - note: those websites *are* working. I check this with my mobile connection (different provider)
- I am on a DELL Precision laptop on Ubuntu 20.04. However, same behaviour can be seen on a windows PC and on an Android smartphone independently from any browser version at all
- When I ping any such URL in a console it says `0 received, 100% package loss`
- There seems to be no logics in what domains or websites work and which not

I do not even have a clue, on what to look or to check? Any help is much appreciated. What further information would you need to narrow the problem down?

Comment: First port of call should be your ISP. If they have DNS issues etc they will be first to know.

Comment: Alright, will try. Hard to get a decent information from their support, though...